# Why can't I pass template function pointers to varargs functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, function-pointers, variadic-functions

The following C++ code does not compile for me in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

template <int X>
int Function()
{
    return X;
}

int Sum(int start, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, start);

    for (;;)
    {
        typedef int (*Callback)();  // typedef required by C standard 7.15.1.1
        Callback func = va_arg(args, Callback);
        if (!func)
            break;
        start += (*func)();
    }

    va_end(args);

    return start;
}

int wmain()
{
    wprintf(L"sum: %d\n", Sum(5, Function<32>, Function<66>, static_cast<int (*)()>(nullptr)));
    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> mycode.cpp(32) : error C2664: 'int Sum(int,...)' : cannot convert argument
>    2 from 'int (__cdecl *)(void)' to '...'
>           Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

I know what this error normally means; it says that your function is overloaded, so you can't take a function pointer unless you cast it to a type that resolves the overload.  But in this case, there is no ambiguity: the type is always int (*)()!

Comment: VS2013 has variadic templates. Is there any reason you aren't using those?

Comment: @chris VS2013 fully supports variadic templates? in vs12 it's absent. May be off-topic but I just wanted to know?

Comment: New CTP just out see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx, also a C++ feature roadmap

Comment: @me.deeiip, Yes, it's built in. 2012 had a CTP with them, which got promoted to built-in support.

Comment: @Dweeberly, The new CTP doesn't include support for variadic templates; they're already supported in 2013. It was the 2012 CTP that had preliminary support.

Comment: I'm working with code that exists already.  The above is a filtered example of the problem I encountered.  It's not really my design choice here.

Comment: By the way, this code compiles in Linux with GCC 4.7.2 in C++11 mode, once I replace "wmain" with "main", of course.

Comment: Works in gcc without c++11 mode (apart from nullptr).  Suggest tagging visual-studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Visual Studio does not properly or fully instanciate the template function before trying to pass it to "...".

Here is a solution which give you the (almost) same syntax for the client code and which compiles and work on visual studio 2010. The trick is to hide the template gimmick inside a more standard interface inheritance. The code is a bit more complexe, but still manageable and safe as it is. Not sure if this will apply to your "real life" problem you probably simplified to post your question here, though.

```
class IFunctor  {
public:
    virtual ~IFunctor() {}
    virtual int value() = 0;
};

template<int X> class Functor : public IFunctor {
public:
    virtual ~Functor() {}
    virtual int value() { return X; }
};

template<int X> IFunctor* Function()
{
    static Functor<X> x;
    return &x;
}

IFunctor *EndFunction()
{
    return nullptr;
}

int Sum(int start, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, start);

    for (;;)
    {
        IFunctor *functor = va_arg(args, IFunctor*);
        if (functor == nullptr) break;
        start += functor->value();
    }

    va_end(args);

    return start;
}

int main()
{
    wprintf(L"sum: %d\n", Sum(5, Function<32>(), Function<66>(), EndFunction()));
    char c = getc(stdin);   
    return 0;
}
```